# how to read value of object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, object

I need to get the value of array of objects

Here is my part of googlemaps code which creates markers

```
var addMarker = function () {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, brigadeStatus) {
                pic = 'images/red.png'; 
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                id: clientId,
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: "ID: " +clientId +"; " +clientStreet_char + ' ' + clientStreet_name + ' ' + clientStreet_adr,
                icon: pic
            });
        }
        clientMarkerId.push(marker);
        clientMarkers[clientId] = marker;
    });
};
```

After I have created three markers, I have opened console of chrome developer tools 
where I have typed >clientMarkerId It shows array and three elements

```
> clientMarkerId
[_.ue, _.ue, _.ue]
```

Clicking on each element show this:

```
[__e3_:Object
click:Object
rightclick:Object
__proto__:Object
__gm:Object
anchorPoint:_.I
changed:(a)
clickable:true
closure_uid_596642721:375
gm_accessors_:Object
gm_bindings_:Object
icon:"images/red.png"
id:10
internalPosition:_.E
map:qg
position:_.E
title:"ID: 10; str. ABC 102"
visible:true
__proto__:qe]
```

Here is also an image

[image]

So, the question is how can I get the value of "icon" ("images/red.png") of any `clientMarkerId` array element?

Comment: [`clientMarkerId[id].getIcon();`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `clientMarkerId[0].icon`?

Replace the 0 with the index of which one you need. Use a loop if you need to get all of them.

Comment: Thanks Anne, it looks so funny because of it's easily.